# how can I use the .map() method and print baby in front of each element in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

```js
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];

const babyAnimals = animals.map((baby) => {
  return `baby ${animals}`;
})
console.log(babyAnimals);
```

I want the code to print

`['baby panda', 'baby turtle', 'baby giraffe', 'baby hippo', 'baby sloth', 'baby human']`

I used the for loop method and it worked but I'm trying to use .map method and I haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: hint: What is the `baby` parameter you got from the map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your map function, you are returning the entire animals array instead of the current element `baby`. You should update your map function to use the current element:

```js
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];

const babyAnimals = animals.map((baby) => {
    return `baby ${baby}`;
})  
console.log(babyAnimals);
```